# Newtonsoft JSON string deserialization with \ escape character issue

Tags: c#, json.net

We have a serialized JSON string like this:

```
{\\"count\":1,\r\n\"value\":[\r\n{\"HOST\":\"\\\\cifs_BI-FileDumps\\BI-FileDumps\\\"}]}
```

Actual value for the above:

```
\\cifs_BI-FileDumps\BI-FileDumps\
```

I tried to convert this with online JSON parser and its working fine as well as valid JSON.

But when we try to deserialize it, we get this error:

> Executed 'ExecuteQueryFunction' (Failed, Id=d6a4875e-7aa8-47e8-b298-16d50f4807b5) System.Private.CoreLib:
>   Exception while executing function: ExecuteQueryFunction.
>   Newtonsoft.Json: Bad JSON escape sequence: \B. Path 'value[0].HOST', line 3, position 30.

Comment: Please help to resolve the same

Comment: Actual value for the above :-   \ \cifs_BI-FileDumps\BI-FileDumps\

Comment: actual value starts with \\

Comment: you will have to encode the field.

Comment: Is the string you show what you see in the debugger?  What does it look like if you look at it in the Text Visualizer or the JSON Visualizer? (to get access to the visualizers in the debugger, look at the variable and click the little magnifying glass icon)

Comment: If the string content is **actually** like that, then that is not JSON. If there had been one backslash in front of the double quotes, then perhaps, but not two, this looks like a doubly escaped string, and the debugger will only escape once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` therefore before serializing, encode that field. After you deserialize you should decode back.

`\cifs_BI-FileDumps\BI-FileDumps\` becomes:

`%5Ccifs_BI-FileDumps%5CBI-FileDumps%5C` after you encode it.

And works other way around when you decode it.

Comment: There should be no need to escape anything **before** serializing to json because any json serializer other than a homebrew one should properly escape problematic characters by itself.

Comment: But the deserializing the below string is throwing error even it contains escape sequence

Comment: "{\"count\":1,\r\n\"value\":[\r\n{\"HOST\":\"\\\\cifs_BI-FileDumps\\BI-FileDumps\\\"}]}"